How to build solana project dependency artifact for integration tests?
I have a project A - which depends on integrating with project B.
I am setting up Rust based integration tests (using solana-program-test) and want to deploy project B of some version (say it's in github at commit XYZ in repo https://github.com/project_b).
I can pull this in as a dependency into my project to access the account structs. But now I am trying to get this to work in my integration test code. The problem is that solana-program-test (as of v1.18.26) requires to add the program by searching for the artifact "program_b.so".
Is there a way to get Anchor or cargo to build the dependency so it's available at test time much like my program is available?
One approach I have is to create some build.rs script which download the dependencies in some tmp/ folder, build the artifact.so, and then put it into fixtures as fixtures/prograb_b.so. But I am hoping there is a simpler way as I'm not sure this will work.

Getting a tool to automatically build it is a bit tricky, but could certainly work as you've outlined. You could use the other repo as a submodule in your repo, and in the same Cargo workspace and build the program in a build.rs script. That way all of the built programs will be in the same target/deploy folder, and solana-program-test will find them all automatically.
Alternatively, and much easier, would be to just download a built version of the program from the chain and put it into tests/fixtures, where solana-program-test also looks by default.
